Blazor bootstrap BarChart possibility to remove DataSet
I'm using the component BarChart with Blazor Bootstrap and I want to know if it's possible to remove a DataSet from the component after it is added. I search in the doc but I didn't find something about this.
Thank's for your help.

Is object a Row in a DataTable?  A Dataset is an object with one or  more DataTables.

You need to provide a better explanation with some code.
